# What will happen if minimal polynomial co-incides with the characteristics polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix such that it's minimal polynomial co-incides with the characteristics polynomial then can we claim that any $n-th$ degree polynomial which annihilates $A$ co-incides with the characteristics polynomial?

If the answer is 'yes' then how?I have thought about it fruitlessly.My thoughts are not well enough to understand this concept clearly.Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ be the minimum polynomial of $M$, fuppose $Q$ is a polynomial with the same degree as $M$ that annihalates $M$.

Write $P$ as $\alpha Q+R$ were $R$ is of degree less than $P$ (we can do this with the division algorithm).

Notice that $0=P(M)=\alpha Q(M)+R(M)=0+R(M)$. This implies $R$ is the zero polynomial (since otherwise it would be a non-zero polynomial of degree less than $P$ that annihalates $M$. We conclude $Q=\alpha P$.

Your case is a particular case of this, you are just saying that $P$ has degree $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  By definition, the minimal polynomial $m_A$ divides any other polynomial that annihilates $A$.  So, if some polynomial $f$ of equal degree annihilates $A$, then $m_A\mid f$, so $m_A = cf$ where $c$ is some constant.

Comment: But @Mark how can I show that $g(t)$ becomes characteristics polynomial of $A$?For if $A = I_2$ then the polynomial $(x-1)(x-2)$ annihilates $A$ though it is not the characteristics polynomial.But here the situation is quite different where degree of minimal polynomial $< 2$.But when characteristics and minimal polynomial co-incides then I can't construct such example.Why?

Comment: What does it mean to annihilate?

Comment: @GuachoPerez From context, I'm assuming they mean $f(A) = 0$.

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay Note here that the minimal polynomial is $x-1$, and the characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)^2$.  To rephrase what I said earlier, if $m_A(x)$ is the minimial polynomial of $A$, then for ANY polynomial $f$ where $f(A) = 0$, we must have that either $f(x) = 0$, or that $f(x) = m_A(x)g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is some other polynomial.  Here, we have that $m_{I_2}(x) = x-1$, and your polynomial is just $m_{I_2}(x)(x-2)$.

Comment: @Mark does the term "annihilating polynomial" have a formal definition or is it like "the tails of the distribution" in statistics, I have not found any information related to either of these two terms on the web and I was wondering if they are a definite thing ir not.

Comment: Sorry.I have misunderstood what you have stated.

Comment: @GuachoPerez I would normally say that $f(A) = 0$ where $f(x)\neq 0$ is a polyomial that $A$ _satisfies_.  This terminology seems to be fairly standard.  Note on this page that the [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) says that a linear operator $A$ satisfies its own characteristic equation.

Answer (score 0):

There are other things that happen when the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial coincide; note that we demand both monic...

First, while there may be eigenvalues with multiplicity greater than one, nevertheless each eigenvalue occurs in a single Jordan block.

Second, if we call our matrix $A,$ then any matrix $B$ that commutes with $A,$ that is $AB=BA,$ is a polynomial in $A,$ of degree no larger than $n-1$ because of Cayley Hamilton, anyway
$$ B = a_0 I + a_1 A + a_2 A^2 + \cdots + a_{n-1} A^{n-1}. $$
The set of such $B$ makes a vector space, it is then dimension $n,$ which is very small. In comparison, the identity matrix commutes with all matrices, in that case dimension $n^2.$ Big.

Here's a simple example, one you can check with 2 by 2 and 3 by 3 matrices. If a diagonal matrix $D$ has $n$ different elements on the diagonal, then it commutes only with other diagonal matrices. These other diagonal matrices may have repetition, for example the identity matrix.